# grpc Server in background thread c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, grpc

I am trying to run an grpc server in a thread in an MFC app.

I have (grpc parts straight from the GRPC example):

`MyAppDlg.h:`

```
#include <thread>
#include <grpcpp\grpcpp.h>

class MyAppDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    MyAppDlg( CString aFileName, CWnd *pParent = NULL );
    virtual ~MyAppDlg();

    std::unique_ptr<grpc::Server> grpcServer;

    std::thread grpcThread;

    void RunServer();
```

`MyAppDlg.cpp:`

```
class GreeterServiceImpl final : public Greeter::Service {
    Status SayHello(ServerContext* context, const HelloRequest* request,
        HelloReply* reply) override {
        std::string prefix("Hello ");
        reply->set_message(prefix + request->name());
        return Status::OK;
    }
};

void MyAppDlg::RunServer() {
    std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:50051");
    GreeterServiceImpl service;
    grpc::EnableDefaultHealthCheckService(true);
    grpc::reflection::InitProtoReflectionServerBuilderPlugin();
    ServerBuilder builder;
    builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
    builder.RegisterService(&service);
    std::unique_ptr<Server> grpcServer(builder.BuildAndStart());
    std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;

    // Wait for the server to shutdown. Note that some other thread must be
    // responsible for shutting down the server for this call to ever return.
    grpcServer->Wait(); <-- Leaving this out causes the server to close immediately again.
}

MyAppDlg::MyAppDlg( CString aFileName, CWnd* pParent /* =NULL */ )
{
    ... stuff ...
    // RunServer(); <-- using this works but blocks the thread
    grpcThread(RunServer); <-- does not work

}

MyAppDlg::~MyAppDlg()
{
    grpcServer->Shutdown();
    grpcThread.join();
}
```

Without the thread, it runs fine (client can connect and call `SayHello`), but blocks the constructor at `RunServer()` because of the `grpcServer->Wait()` call. Trying it with the thread, I get a compiler error: `call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type`

Not calling `grpcServer->Wait()` causes the server to close immediately after `RunServer()` exits, although the variable `grpcServer` is still in the scope as long as the class instance is running.

How do I properly start a `grpcServer` and put it in the background?

Comment: Hi, were you able to achieve what you wanted to do ? I am in the same position in trying to do the same thing.

Comment: I actually did, somehow. However, the whole project was shifted to C# for other reasons, so I acutally don't remember how I solved it. And since it was just some tinkering around to check the feasability, it's not in any repo, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line within `MyAppDlg::RunServer()`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Server> grpcServer(builder.BuildAndStart());
```

You're defining a local variable called `grpcServer` instead of assigning to the class data member of the same name, so it's going out of scope as soon as `RunServer()` returns.  I think that should just be:

```
grpcServer.reset(builder.BuildAndStart());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the server in a separate thread, that is the

```cpp
grpcThread(Runserver);
```

You need to associate the RunServer method with an object instance, in this case "this":

```cpp
grpcTread(std::bind(&MyAppDlg::RunServer, this));
```

This should fix the compilation error.

And as Mark pointed out, you have a class member grpcServer, but you declare a local variable grpcServer in RunServer which goes out of scope after RunServer exits.

What's more, even if you do the `Wait()` inside RunServer and run it on a separate thread (which should work just fine), the `MyAppDlg::~MyAppDlg()` will not shutdown the server since it will shutdown the `MyAppDlg::grpcServer`, which is different from the local variable `grpcServer` inside `RunServer`.

Comment: But if you dont want to run it in a separate thread, Mark D. Roth has the answer.